# dim display on idle (Windows 7, NOT a laptop)

Tags: windows, screensaver

This might be a weird request, but my googlefu has been weak.  I want my Windows 7 desktop to dim after x minutes/seconds of being idle.  I don't care if it's an actual SCR or an app that runs in the background or a hack that enables laptop settings.

I found one called AutoDimmer but on their site it says "XP/2000 ONLY", which I verified anyway... doesn't work.

Comment: Just to clarify - the built in put-the-monitors-to-sleep isn't acceptable, you want it dim but lit?  (The 'laptop settings' are specific to those LCD panels, you can't just dim a monitor LCD willy-nilly like that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across a screensaver called [Power Dimmer](http://www.whitsoftdev.com/powerdimmer/):

> Power Dimmer is a Windows screen saver application that, once activated, will gradually dim your screen, fading it from full brightness to a final brightness level that you set. While the screen is dimmed, you can still see all of your windows, as well as any on-screen activity. Move the mouse or press a key and your screen will be restored to full brightness.

Although it says for Windows 200/XP only, I've just tried it out on my Windows 7 64bit desktop and it works fine for me.

Comment: This is the exact one I tried, however upon trying it again I realize the default fade time is 180 seconds which is obviously 3 minutes... too long for me to notice in my impatient tests.  Works great.  Wish it faded back in, but that's obviously a limitation of the screensaver functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I set mine to 5 seconds and 20% brightness

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe this is something you can accomplish on a desktop computer.  The monitor is a separate piece of hardware on a desktop, and not integrated like a laptop.  If there was a way to do it, you will probably find it as a setting on your monitor and not via Windows.

Comment: Laptop panels aren't any more integrated than desktop monitors -- they often use the same communication protocols and signaling systems (e.g. still using VGA/DVI/etc.), just with customized connectors for the tiny space.  However, laptop panels are more likely to expose features via software (e.g. brightness/contrast) than desktop monitors, simply because there's less space for hardware buttons and features like auto-dimming are far more useful on portables.  That doesn't mean that desktop panels *can't* support those features, they just often don't.

Comment: Apple's LCD monitors are prime examples of desktop monitors that have software controllable brightness built-in.